# Install Windows 7 after Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-9.10, installation, multi-boot

I've Ubuntu Karmic Koala 9.10 installed in my HDD.
My parents can't get used to it, so I must install Windows 7.

I'm afraid of this: **Windows boot must be on the first hard disk/partition in order to boot**. I've read it somewhere, and I now I'm not sure if I'll need to remove Ubuntu to install Windows 7 first.

Does any1 know some serious guide for doing this? or some essential steps, tips...

Comment: My mom have been using Ubuntu (actually Kubuntu) for a few years now, it's a matter of taking some time to learn it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What worked for me was installing Windows 7 regularly, on a different partition of course. Then restoring GRUB, described in the section **Restoring GRUB** from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) and **Recovering GRUB after reinstalling Windows** from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

My /boot/grub/menu.lst looks like so:

> title     Windows
>
> root      (hd0,1)
>
> map (hd0,0) (hd0,1)
>
> map (hd0,1) (hd0,0)
>
> makeactive
>
> chainloader   +1

The map part fools Windows into thinking it's the first hdd/partition.

Good luck~

Answer (score 0):

I have used these instructions to set up a dual boot -
 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1035999

> **“How to” Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 (Ubuntu installed first)**
>   This guide does not work for Karamic or future releases, For that see [page 14](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1035999&page=14) and follow the link provided by presence1960 for how to dual boot with Grub2 (requires some reading) I will update this guide for grub2 when I have more time
>   I have recently seen many posts from people trying to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 beta, but not succeeding. So I tried it out myself and found a solution.Index
>   1.  Obtain a copy of Windows7.
>   2.  Partition your disk with gparted.
>   3.  Install Windows7.
>   4.  Re-install Grub.
>   5.  Edit Grub to List Windows 7.
>   6.  Have Fun.