# Why can't I install Ubuntu 10.04 on a system that already has Ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gparted

Ubuntu 10.04 is beautiful. I love it. I am dying to install it on my PC, alongside the existing Ubuntu 8.04 (from which I write this message right now).

But... it won't let me!

When I reach the partitioning stage (manual!) Ubuntu 10.04 sees my two HDDs as **one** RAID volume.

It doesn't see all the partitions I already have in place in /dev/sda and /dev/sdb.

Even Windows 7 doesn't behave like this... (yes, I actually managed to install Windows 7 64-bit in dual-boot configuration with Ubuntu 8.04 [on this same system](https://superuser.com/questions/219271/cant-install-windows-7-on-extended-partition)).

Note: GParted on Ubuntu 10.04 (live CD) sees the partition intended for Ubuntu 10.04 (/dev/sda4) perfectly, but is unable to format it.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade

Comment: @Aki, I am not interested in upgrading. I am interested in a fresh install, **alongside** the existing 8.04, in a dual-boot configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. See solution [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/why-cant-i-install-10-04-on-a-system-that-already-has-8-04-a-853016/).

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove that partition (Windows Disk management should allow you to do that) so "free space" is created and then try to install.

Comment: Sorry, I tried that already. It didn't help. There is something fundamentally wrong in the way 10.04 sees or mounts my disks. Is there a way to disable this "Auto-RAID" when booting form the LiveCD?

Comment: @AndroidEve You might want to try to ask this on askubuntu.com

Comment: Thanks and +1 for bringing askubuntu.com to my attention. I didn't know about it. (there are soooooo many forums nowadays. It's mind boggling)

Comment: @AndroidEve you're very welcome! n_n